# python extract data from excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel file which has data like below :

```
Message Type    Message Text    Message Local Date/Time
Card Admitted   Admitted 'Gulevata, Lena [Default]' (Card: 447430)   at 'EMEA-ISR-HZY 01.02.02 GF BACK DOOR [Default]' (IN).    9/17/2018 5:19
Card Admitted   Admitted 'Gulevata, Lena [Default]' (Card: 447430)   at 'EMEA-ISR-HZY 01.02.02 GF BACK DOOR [Default]' (IN).    9/17/2018 5:57
Card Admitted   Admitted 'Gulevata, Lena [Default]' (Card: 447430)   at 'EMEA-ISR-HZY 01.01.01 GF MAIN ENTRANCE [Default]' (IN).    9/17/2018 5:58
Card Admitted   Admitted 'Gulevata, Lena [Default]' (Card: 447430)   at 'EMEA-ISR-HZY 01.02.01 GF NORTH ELEVATOR LOBBY [Default]' (IN). 9/17/2018 5:59
```

And I want it to convert it to a dataframe like below for further processing. Basically I want to extract the Card Number from the Message Text . Any pointers using Python and Pandas would be helpful

```
Message Type    Message Text    Message Local Date/Time
Card Admitted   447430  9/17/2018 5:19
Card Admitted   447430  9/17/2018 5:57
Card Admitted   447430  9/17/2018 5:58
Card Admitted   447430  9/17/2018 5:59
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something along the lines of:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(<file_name>)
df['Meassge Text'] = [x.split('card: ')[1].split(')')[0] for x in df['Meassge Text']]
```